# Copy host file to docker container during build

Tags: docker

Is there a way to copy a host file into a docker container during the build process, i.e. docker build -t  .

For example adding this line fails:

```
COPY /home/my_name/file_I_want /root
```

Because docker is trying to copy from the /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-xxxxx path.

What's the use of the COPY command, which is supposed to copy from host to container, when it can't even access the host directory structure properly?

Comment: You can only `COPY` files from the host from the same directory tree that contains the `Dockerfile` (and more specifically the directory tree rooted at the path argument to `docker build`).  `COPY ./file_I_want /root`

Answer (score 1):

The `COPY` command does not copy from host to container, it copies from the build context to a new image layer. There is a very large difference between the two as you see.

The build command, like other docker commands, is client/server based. The build may run on a remote server with no access to the machine running the docker command. To support copying files into your image, you pass the build context as the last argument to the build command. This context is often `.` indicating the current directory. It could easily be any directory. You can further change what is included in that context with a `.dockerignore` file. The very first step of the build from the client side is to tar up the context and send it to the server which is unpacked in a temporary location. To avoid infinite loops (sending the temp directory to the server which is unpacked in a sub directory of that temp directory, repeating until you run out of disk space) and slow builds in general, you should minimize this context by sending only the directory needed to build your application.

The difference between an image and container is a bit less important here. The container is an instance, often running with an isolated process inside, based off the definition from an image. When copying files into your image, it's not necessary to create a temporary container, like you would normally with a `RUN` command. The end result of all of these commands in a Dockerfile is a new image, which you can then run as one or more containers, or push/pull from registries.

The solution is to make the first directory in your copy command part of your build context, typically the same directory as your Dockerfile, and copy from that relative path.

Answer (score 0):

COPY is to copy a file from host to the docker image.

Don't copy to the "root" folder which it will not have access. You need to add command for write permission if using root or system folder.

Try change to "tmp" folder and see. "tmp" has write permission.

COPY /home/my_name/file_I_want /tmp

You can create folder, also you need to give access.

Regarding the path,yes I have also face the same. Its taking the relative path.

Comment: Most base Docker images start off running as root so permission issues aren't usually an issue.  It's extremely common (and vastly simplifies operation) to install binaries into system directories like `/usr/bin` inside a Dockerfile.